# Session works on Local Machine but not on Server

Tags: php, session

I have created a small website which allows users to create their accounts and this works fine on my local machine. i.e ... i can create 2 accounts and access those from ac from differet browsers and also navigate in the other ac and vice versa.. now i got all these files on my server and it works pretty much the same except.. its does not work while navigating other accounts.. the problem that i am facing is .. when i visit other profile the value of the session variable changes from the logged in user id to the visited profiles id..

How i tested.. i have a home page and i echo the logged in user id and the visited profile id..

For the logged in user.. its like

```
echo 'my id '.$_SESSION['user_id'];
echo 'friends id '.$_GET['user_id'];
```

now lets say my id is 1 and friends id is 2.. the output on my local machine is 1 and 1 for my home page and for friends page its 1 and 2.. however on the server its 1 and 1 for my home page and 2 and 2 for friends page... that's the problem.

Comment: Without seeing the relevant portion of code on how you get and set your session it would be hard to tell you.

Comment: If you could be more clear and show us more of your code, that could help us to help you.

Comment: Well its nothing much but...
 
if(isset($_GET['user_id'])){
      echo 'my id '.$_SESSION['user_id'];
      echo 'friends id '.$_GET['user_id']; 
}

Comment: So.. how do you set the sessions?